# How to add custom dropdown inside the datatable plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTable 1.10+ and I need to display a dynamic dropdown inside the DataTable jquery plugin which should be aligned properly in the top in between the paging and search filter.

I embedded some html after DataTable initialization inside the table to display it(see demo below). But is there any better version of doing this which will be helpful in creating dropdown with dynamic values.

Here's a demo of what I've tried and want looks like,  [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman/qxc26rmd/20/)

```
var html =  '<div id="custome_dropdown"><div id="example_dropdown" class="dataTables_length"><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Show</label><select id="filter"><option value="firefox">firefox</option><option value="mozilla">mozilla</option></select></div></div>';

$(html).insertAfter("#example_wrapper #example_length");
```

Comment: Take a look at this. https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html

Comment: Yep, you need to look into the the `DOM` option as @pmeyer said. But you could also do some cool stuff in the initComplete (https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) function to populate your newly added div... i.e. create and populate your select from values you've collected on your initial spin through the data.