# Sorting jQuery DataTables from a single Select Option

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, dropdown

I've been trying to see if this is even possible, so let me explain what I'm looking for.

I have a basic table that I'm making sortable with jQuery DataTables, no custom options, just the simple basic initialization.

```
$("#myTable").DataTable();
```

Is there a way that I connect myTable to a select form element, and have the table be sortable by that select dropdown ONLY?

Comment: This might help, https://stackoverflow.com/q/16565568/1793718 Basically if the user chooses an option in the select element one will expect the column to be filtered(instead of sorting). So I think its better to filter the data and display it. Please see my question here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39169291/1793718 I couldn't find a better solution. You might need to write some custom plugin to do that. Or head to https://datatables.net/forums/ and post your question there for other solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can disable sorting for each column using `columnDefs.orderable` option and then sort the table with [`order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) API method when value of drop-down control changes.

For example:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'columnDefs': [
      { 'orderable': false, 'targets': '_all' }
   ],
   'order': [0, 'asc']       
});

$('#example-sort').on('change', function(){
   table.order([$(this).val(), 'asc']).draw();
})
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/w05zdr3q/) for code and demonstration.